# Reassignment of 'self' in a method: Python 3.8

Tags: python, self

In a method of a class:

```
def weight(self, grid):

    ...

    if self.is_vertical:
        self = self.T

    ...
```

I'd like to reassign `self` to its transposed value if the condition is true. Depending on the `if`-statement, I'd like to use `self` in a method later in its original or transposed condition.

As I understand, in a method, `self` is just a parameter name, but not the real reference or a pointer to an instance of a class, as in C++ or similar languages, so I can freely reassign it for use inside the scope of a method.

My question is why PyCharm's Inspection Info warns me that

> ...first parameter, such as 'self' or 'cls', is reassigned in a method. In most cases imaginable, there's no point in such reassignment, and it indicates an error.

while it works fine? Why does it indicates an error?

Comment: `self` is indeed a reference to the instance

Comment: I think it's warning you because what you're doing is needlessly confusing. You could easily just use another variable inside your method instead of reassigning `self`.

Comment: `self` is a reference but the point of `self` is to give you a way to access the object inside its method. If you reassign that, you have no way of doing so anymore.

Comment: Yeah, IMO you shouldn't mess with self, it's gonna be very confusing for someone else reading your code.

Comment: What does it mean to take the transpose of an instance object?  You replace the instance with one of its attributes.  Unless that attribute is another instance of the same class, this is a semantic error.

Comment: I assume you have some 2D array, and would like to transpose that? If so pandas has functions to do so, and you wouldn't need a class + attribute to store such information

Comment: If you assign `self` to something else, this is only valid in that particular method. You are not changing the object at the caller's location. You cannot replace the current object at the caller.

Comment: @Prune, I indeed have a geometric object with some specific functionality and I'd like to transpose it as a matrix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why does it indicates an error?

Because there's no good reason to do it. Nothing uses the `self` variable automatically, so there's no need to reassign it. If you need a variable that sometimes refers to the object that the method was called on but could also hold some other value, use a different variable for this.

```
def mymethod(self):
    cur = self
    ...
    cur = cur.T
    ...
```

Note that `self` is just a local variable within this method. Reassigning `self` doesn't have any effect on the object itself, or the variable that the method was called on. It's practically useless to do this, so it almost always indicates that the programmer was confused. That's why Pycharm warns about it.

Since everyone expects `self` to refer to the object that the method was called on, reassigning it will also be confusing to other programmers. When working on code later in the method, they may not realize that `self` might not refer to that object. Imaging trying to have a conversation with someone who says "From now on, whenever I say 'me' or 'I', I actually mean that guy over there."

This is just the flip side of why we have the `self` and `cls` naming convention in the first place. As far as Python is concerned, you can use any name for the first parameter of a method. But we recommend everyone use these names so that when we read each others' code, we won't have to remember what variable refers to the current object in each method.

Python itself doesn't care, it won't cause an error message there.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! But wouldn't it be simpler and cleaner not to use a different variable and just go on with ```self```, since it is already a local variable and does not affect actual object's state?

Comment: Because it's confusing, since everyone expects `self` to refer to a particular object.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar :)